# How to leave a kubectl cluster from cli?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

How can I disconnect from a kubernetes cluster from gitbash, I connected once and I can't "disconnect" or make the cluster name go away.

[image]

Comment: Switch the context using `kubectl config use-context my-cluster-name`

Comment: As @Cjmarkham indicated, you're not "connected" to the cluster, that is your shell prompt you have configured to display your current kubectl context name.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks a lot. really what I needed was to run the command:

```
kubectl config unset current-context
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not connected, it's on your kubectl configs context, you can unset it or use (switch to) another context.

#### How to see existing contexts

```bash
kubectl config get-contexts
```

#### How to switch to another context

```bash
kubectl config use-context <context-name>
```

You may have taken context name from the last command,

e.g. if you've enabled Kubernetes on your docker-desktop, you can use its context with this command:

```bash
kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```

#### How to unset

```bash
kubectl config unset current-context
```

If you unset your current context, you will not have any active context anymore and if you run commands like `kubectl get pods` you will get this error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```