# kubectl is trying to connect to gcloud instead of docker desktop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubectl, docker-desktop

My kubectl is connecting to GCP by default. I was trying few changes locally and deploying to Docker Desktop Kubernetes.

I remember it was working earlier. But recently when this is executed:

```
kubectl get pods
```

It gives-

```
WARNING: the gcp auth plugin is deprecated in v1.22+, unavailable in v1.25+; use gcloud instead. To learn more, consult https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
```

Any clue how to fix this kubectl error and let it show Kubernetes stuffs from Docker Desktop also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by switching the context to `docker-desktop`. Now it shows from Docker Desktop Kubernetes instead connecting to GCP.

`kubectl config use-context docker-desktop`

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` to avoid this warning now and in the future to avoid errors.

The easiest way to install the plugin is as follows:

1- Update your Google Cloud SDK

```
gcloud components update
```

2- Install the plugin (if not already installed with the update)

```
gcloud components install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
```

---

Story behind this:

`kubectl` starting from version **1.25** will no longer have a built-in authentication mechanism for `GKE` and instead, you will have to install the mentioned plugin for `kubectl` to support authentication of `GKE`. Read the full details [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this warning message basically, you need to export gke gcloud auth plugin in .bashrc file

```
export USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True
```

Added answer in details please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72274548/how-to-remove-warning-in-kubectl-with-gcp-auth-plugin/73986883#73986883)

Answer (score 0):

It's your kubectl active context, you can use `docker-desktop` as your active context:

```bash
kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```

You can also see other existing contexts

```bash
kubectl config get-contexts
```

And switch to them:

```bash
kubectl config use-context <context-name>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218879/12972198) might be helpful.

You can also run command below for more information:

```
kubectl config -h
```